# Second segue from TableViewController creating SIGABRT error relating to the first

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have created a NoteBook application within a larger app. I have all the functionality working including a segue to an Add Note page which triggers programatically from clicking a note (to edit it) or a + barButtonItem.

I need a second segue to send the user back to the home page of the app, but every way I seem to try it conflicts with the existing segue I have in place.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the second segue to work. They both have different identifiers which I am referencing in the methods. Its just the goHome segue that will not work...

class NoteBookViewController: UITableViewController, NoteViewDelegate {

```
func didUpdateNoteWithTitle(newTitle: String, andBody newBody: String) {
    self.noteBookEntries[self.selectedIndex] ["title"] = newTitle
    self.noteBookEntries[self.selectedIndex] ["body"] = newBody

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    saveNotesArray()
}

var noteBookEntries = [[String:String]] ()

@IBAction func newNote() {

    var newNote = ["title" : "", "body" : ""]
    noteBookEntries.insert(newNote, at: 0)

    self.selectedIndex = 0

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    saveNotesArray()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editNoteBookSegue", sender: nil)
}

var selectedIndex = -1

func saveNotesArray() {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(noteBookEntries, forKey: "notes")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let newNote = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "notes") as? [[String:String]] {
        noteBookEntries = newNote
    }

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.reply, target: self, action: #selector(NoteBookViewController.navigateToNextViewController))

}

func navigateToNextViewController(){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return noteBookEntries.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "CELL")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = noteBookEntries[indexPath.row]["title"]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        noteBookEntries.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(noteBookEntries, forKey: "notes")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editNoteBookSegue", sender: nil)
}

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let notesEditorVC = segue.destination as! NewNoteBookEntryViewController

        notesEditorVC.navigationItem.title = noteBookEntries[self.selectedIndex] ["title"]
        notesEditorVC.noteBodyText = noteBookEntries[self.selectedIndex] ["body"]
        notesEditorVC.delegate = self

}
```

}

[error message relating to original segue - this segue works until the second is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjdQD.png)

Comment: I have also tried using an `@IBAction func` linked to a barButtonItem added in the storyboard, but that just presents the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `prepareForSegue` method first line is:

```
let notesEditorVC = segue.destination as! NewNoteBookEntryViewController
```

This method is called for each of your segues. When it is called for your first segue it works totally fine because the destination view controller is, in fact, of type `NewNoteBookEntryViewController`.

However, when this method is called for your second segue, the destination controller is of different type. So, you get a crash when you force downcast it.

You should add some logic to your `prepareForSegue` method so that you distinguish between segues. For example:

```
if segue.identifier == "addNote" {
    let notesEditorVC = segue.destination as! NewNoteBookEntryViewController
    //some other code
}
```

Comment: Thats one step closer - Now I get back to the home screen, but the Navigation bar from the TableViewController is still showing at the top of the screen... Is there a way to force this to be dismissed?

Comment: thats probably because you haven't updated the title of your Navigation bar. You are doing this for the "addNote" segue - insert the code which would do it for your second segue as well. If this doesn't solve the problem - can you share the code through github?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the logic and then adding this to the destination controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {   
   self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true) 
}
```